# apply a function to each secuence of rows in a column

Tags: pandas

I have a df like this:

```
     xx
A    3
B    4
C    1
D    5
E    7
F    6
G    3
H    5
I    8
J    5
```

I would like to apply the pct_change function to column XX to every 5 rows:

to generate the following output:

```
         xx
A       NaN
B  0.333333
C -0.750000
D  4.000000
E  0.400000
F       NaN
G -0.500000
H  0.666667
I  0.600000
J -0.375000
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `np.arange` by length of `df` and use integer divison by `5` and pass it to `groupby` function:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 5).pct_change()
print (df)
         xx
A       NaN
B  0.333333
C -0.750000
D  4.000000
E  0.400000
F       NaN
G -0.500000
H  0.666667
I  0.600000
J -0.375000
```